# PHP + Joomla (Sourcerer Plugin). Any Obvious Errors?

Tags: php, joomla

Here is my article.  PHP code is wrapped in {source} tags, and sourcerer magically runs the PHP in the Article.  I have successfully used Sourcerer previously; but now it is throwing some odd errors.

```
{source}

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $connect = mysql_connect("host","user","pass"); 

    mysql_select_db("<redacted>", $connect);

    $term = $_POST['userid'];
    $getUserid = mysql_query("SELECT itemid, first, last FROM tenants where CONCAT(first, last) LIKE '%$term%'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($getUserId);
?>
{/source}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">itemID</td>
        <td align="center">First</td>
        <td align="left">Last</td>
    </tr>
    {source}
    <?php 
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    ?>
    {/source}
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            {source} <?php echo $data['id']; ?> {/source}
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">
            {source} <?php echo $data['first']; ?>{/source}
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            {source} <?php echo $data['last']; ?>{/source}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{source}
<?php
} 
}
?>
{/source}

Enter a Search Term: <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register Now" style="width: 130px; height: 30px;" />
```

The errors, when accessing the article are:

```
[Mon Nov 16 15:03:41 2015] [warn] [client 74.84.255.79] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /mnt/data/vhosts/<redacted>/plugins/system/sourcerer/helper.php(607) : runtime-created function on line 17, referer: http://host/
[Mon Nov 16 15:03:41 2015] [warn] [client 74.84.255.79] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /mnt/data/vhosts/<redacted>/plugins/system/sourcerer/helper.php on line 612, referer: http://host/
```

In helper.php, this is line 607:

```
$temp_PHP_func = create_function('&$src_vars, &$article, &$Itemid, &$mainframe, &$app, &$document, &$doc, &$database, &$db, &$user', $src_script);
```

Here is 612:

```
$src_new_vars = $temp_PHP_func($src_vars, $article, $Itemid, $mainframe, $app, $document, $doc, $database, $db, $user);
```

I would appreciate any help at all.  I am at a complete loss here.

Comment: Well for starters you're using `mysql_*` which is deprecated. Instead you should be using the Joomla Database class for database queries. Secondly, why have you not hidden your database connection information? Do you want someone to inject data into your database? Don't use `$_POST` with Joomla (Look at JInput). Overall, I'll say you really need to look at the Joomla documentation. One thing you need to remember is, Joomla has it's own API, so use it!

Comment: We've removed your credentials/website and abs. path from your question. For your website safety make sure to always remove credentials from your code snippets.

Comment: Instead of managing so much in the articles, I would suggest you to create your customized module and then load that module in the article through plugin.